# Magento2 : Import/Export is not visible in Admin section

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, import, importexport

I am having an issue in Magento Admin. The import/export menu is not visible. When I open the URL directly, `It shows a blank page.`

[image]

[image]

Please help, it's urgent.

Comment: Did you change anything or installed new module?

Comment: Yes, I have some custom modules installed, I disabled them all and then tried, but it was having same issue

Comment: can you check log?

Comment: yes, no error over there too.

Comment: Are you admin user with administration role? Or you have created any user which doesn't have enough permission?

Comment: I am the admin user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83114/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-manish-joy).

Comment: Could you share the resolution, please?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159002)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159002)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to debug it.

- Check in administrator role that Import/Export is not un-selected.
- Can you create a new user using command `bin/magento admin:user:create` and login to admin panel using these newly created credentials to check if you can see Import/Exports.
- Disable all the custom modules one-by-one to figure out which module is causing issue.
- Enable developer module using command `bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` and afterwards check if you can find something in log.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 methods that I can see:

**solution 1:** find the string `Magento_Backend::system_convert` into your codebase (`app/code` and `vendor/magento`). Then, hopefully, that should show your your items menu nodes as per the screenshot below.

[image]

If you find the, that is half of the battle sorted as you just have to work out why they don't show up. You may try shorter versions as it may have been mispellt accidentally.

**solution 2:** If you don't find them, I suggest you could create a new menu node in a custom module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Magento_ImportExport::system_convert_import" title="Import" translate="title" module="Magento_ImportExport" sortOrder="10" parent="Magento_Backend::system_convert" action="adminhtml/import" resource="Magento_ImportExport::import"/>    
    </menu>
</config>
```

The key is your new menu item should have the action value set to: `action="adminhtml/import"`

**solution 3:** I am still assuming admin permissions and all the suggestions kindly made have been checked of course. This method is more drastic but you can delete vendor folder and run `composer install`. (Make a backup is always useful)